# HttpDigest authentication using google http client on Android

Tags: android, google-api-java-client

Is there anyway I can implement Http Digest Authentication using Google Http Java Client on Android, the request doesn't seem to have any exposed methods where I can specify the authentication.

Thanks.

Akshay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a feature request filed here: http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/issues/detail?id=163

You can implement this manually by calling HttpRequest.getHeaders().setAuthorization(String), but you'd need to implement the logic to compute the "Authorization" header.  If someone can provide the Java logic to compute the "Authorization" header for HTTP Digest, please post it here and we can mark that as the better answer :)